# VS2019 Enterprise Code Coverage showing only Unit Test DLLs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, visual-studio-2019

I created a fresh solution with .Net Core exe project. I added an MSTest v2 project too.
I ran Analyze Code coverage for All tests, but I have ony received coverage data fot the test project, and not for the main .Net Core project.

Then I have added a .Net Core dll, still no sucess.
Then I have added .Net Framework exe and .Net Framework dll. I rebuilt a solution and ran Code coverage, but still only MSTest V2 project appears in the results.
Then I have added an Nunit project. This time the result shows MSTest v2 and Nunit project, but none of the projects to be tested.

I also tried to add [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]. I tried to enable Autodetect runsettings file. Nothing helped.

I also tried adding this code to main project:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

No effect.

I read that if I add a custom runsettings file, things might start to work. However, I think this is just a workaround, as when I asked to run Code Coverage on my collegue's Visual Studio, all projects appear in the result.

Looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is simple and stupid, but still may solve a tonne of time to an unexperienced unit tester.
The problem is that it is not enough just to add a test project and to add a reference from it to the main project. And even having a test class which does not test anything in the main project does not work. 
The real solution is just to add a class which tests at least one method in the main project.
This way the code coverage will get activated and show results, showing you have one method covered. Thus, it seems not possible to have a main project in the coverage results stating 0% of the project is covered. You will always need to have at least minimal coverage.